# Laravel 5.1 - showing related products through pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I'm stuck on this way too long to solve it myself, so here's my question:

My database is filled by clothes. I want to show related clothes based on color.

My relationships:

(Product.php)

```
public function colors(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Color', 'colors_products', 'FK_product', 'FK_color');
    }
```

(Color.php)

```
 public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'colors_products', 'FK_color', 'FK_product');
    }
```

So every `product` has multiple `colors`. I want to show related pieces on the same page. So if I'm looking at a piece with the color "red" and "black", I want to show both related clothes labeled with "red" and/or "black". So it doesn't have to be both red AND black.

How can I get all clothes with one of the (sometimes multiple) colors like the piece i'm watching?

**UPDATE**

`Product::with('colors')->whereIn('id', $arColors)->get();` is part of the solution. When I have a product with 2 colors (red & black) I see the related products with only black or only red. But when I watch a product with only black, the related items with multiple colors do not show.

Comment: What colors are listed in the $arColor array?  How do you identify 'red&black' in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL's answer is close. I think you want to use whereHas() for this. Given that your colors array is readily available from your active product, let's say it's called $color_ids.

To load all other products that match one of these colors, try this:

```
$related_products = Product::whereHas('colors', function($query) use ($color_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $color_ids);
})->get();
```

whereIn() is documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

whereHas() is documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help you.

```
Color::with('products')->whereIn('color', ['red', 'black'])->get();
```

This will give you the colors and all the products associate with it.

**Update:**
According to your update, you can try this.

```
Product::with(['color' => function($q) use ($colorArray) { 
                             $q->whereIn('color', $colorArray); }])
       ->has('color')
       ->get();
```

I have not run this, but hope to work.

Comment: `Product::with('colors')->whereIn('id', $arColors)->get();`  is part of the solution. 

When I have a product with 2 colors (red & black) I see the related products with only black or only red. But when I watch a product with only black, the related items with multiple colors do not show.

Comment: Products will be included within the colors object.

Comment: Thanks for the update. 

I don't want to discard the multiple color products. :)

Still a problem though:  I receive all the related products, but also wrong products which doesn't even have a link with that product.. :/

Comment: It didn't changed the output. Still clothes with no link whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use relationships and are fine with using views (or use a database supporting it), you could create a view like this:

```
create 
    view related_products 
as 
    select distint 
        a.FK_product as FK_product,
        b.FK_product as FK_related_product 
    from 
        colors_products as a 
    join colors_products as b 
        on (a.FK_color = b.FK_color and a.FK_product <> b.FK_product);
```

This should join all products having at least one color in common.

Now you can add a relationship to your model, like this:

```
    public function relatedProducts()
    {
      return $this->belongstoMany('App\Product', 'related_products', 'FK_related_product');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. It isn't the way I want to be solving this though.